# Strange behavior when scrolling to element using query parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the function that scrolls to the target:

```
function navigateTo(target) {
    var elementTop = $('#'+target).offset().top;
    console.log('Navigating to ' + target + ' (' + elementTop + 'px)');
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: elementTop 
    }, 800, 'swing');
}
```

It works great when I click on my navigation links:

```
$('.nav').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    navigateTo(target);
    window.history.pushState(target, target, 'index.html?page=' + target);
});
```

However, when I try to use it on pageload with a query parameter, it does not scroll to the right spot.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var page = getUrlParameter('page');
    if (page != false) {
        navigateTo(page);
    }
});
```

The further down the page the target element is, the more off the mark it gets.  What am I missing?

I added some logging.  These are navigating to the same spot with each method:

> Navigating to contact (3308px)
>
> Navigating to contact (3883px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the call was being made before all the elements were done loading, thus the height discrepancy. I moved everything to `load` instead of `ready` and it is working great.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    if (getUrlParameter('page') != false) {
        navigateTo(getUrlParameter('page'));
    }
});
```